# MySQL InnoDB - блокировка чтения, пока не будет добавлена новая запись

Tags: php, mysql

Я пробовал читать по поводу блокировки в MySQL, но тема все-равно остается совершенно непонятной.

Суть проблемы:

Таблица со следующими столбцами:
`id` - Индекс, Primary, Autoincrement;
`id_order` - Id Заказа;
`name` - Имя заказавшего

Суть в том, что `id` увеличивается без моего вмешательства, а вот следующий `id_order` я должен прописывать сам.

Порядок действий:

1. Берем последний `id_order`
2. Выполняем вычисления в PHP.
3. Добавляем в таблицу строку с `id_order`, равный либо последнему+1, либо 0.

Суть в том, что при 2 одновременных заказах, получится 2 новых записи с одинаковым `id_order`.

Как я понимаю, `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` мне тут не поможет, так как он разлочит последнюю запись сразу же после того, как получит ее order_id.

Т.е., по идее, мне нужно залочить запись с последним `id_order`, выполнить все нужные мне действия, и уже затем разлочить ее.

Я не могу понять, как мне это сделать.

Пожалуйста, никаких предложений по изменению структуры таблицы. Да, криво сделано изначально.

Comment: Учитывая, что у вас вставка, а не update то конечно select for update не поможет. Боюсь только полное блокирование таблицы. Или может пересмотреть логику php кода и все действия выполнить одним SQL-запросом

Comment: Выбирайте, что Вам больше по вкусу. Первое - пока одним пользователем процедура _залочить запись с последним id_order, выполнить все нужные мне действия, и уже затем разлочить ее_ не окончена, остальные получают отказ. Или второе - потенциально возможно появление "дырок" в нумерации по этому полю, но зато никто никого не ждёт, а дыры потом и закрыть можно.

Comment: Дырки неприемлемы. Отказ тоже, это интернет-магазин, как никак.

Comment: А что, нет отдельной команды для того чтобы сначала залочить. А потом уже отдельно разблокировать?

Comment: Вы бы текущую логику в php описали. когда берется 0 когда следующий id. В 90% случаев вся логика спокойно пишется в одном запросе. Если конечно принятие решение не зависит от каких то внешних данных которые получаются только после select из БД

Comment: Не хотелось бы строить многоэтажные запросы. Я понимаю, это, наверное, эффективно с точки зрения производительности. Но в плане читаемости и дальнейшего изменения это ужас.

Comment: _Дырки неприемлемы. Отказ тоже_ А варианта, когда ни того, ни другого, не бывает. Выбирайте. Я бы предложил выбрать вариант с дырами, а выделение нового номера выполнять не MAX()+1, а первого свободного - есть дырка, используется её номер, нет - берётся следующий. При таком подходе средний срок жизни дырки будет непродолжительным, а строгое соответствие этой нумерации штампам времени вряд ли критично. Правда, придётся создавать систему резервирования номера "вручную", но это несложно.

Comment: А главное - если это магазин, то я навылет не понимаю, зачем такие сложности. Ну не может быть, чтобы вычисления по пункту 2 как-то использовали полученное в пункте 1 значение. Что с этим номером заказа делать-то? умножать? отнимать? логарифм взять? ерунда ж получится... А коли так - поменять местами пункты 1 и 2, и всё шоколадно.

Comment: Дырки не устраивают. Заказы отображаются в неправильном порядке.
Да и я привел самый простой случай. У нас дубли заказов с одинаковыми id и неправильное количество товара из-за того, что перейдя с тормоза MyISAM на InnoDB, получили, что так как сначала берется количество товаров, производятся манипуляции, а затем все записывается обратно, то без лока получается то, что имеем.

Comment: _Заказы отображаются в неправильном порядке._ Они отображаются строго в том порядке, который определён секцией ORDER BY текста запроса. Если порядок неправилен - значит, неправилен запрос. А если нужен хронологический порядок, то сортировать надо по штампу времени (создания или последней корректировки), а никак не по эфемерному "номеру". Дубли заказов у вас не от смены движка, а от ошибочной DDL - отсутствует уникальный индекс. А неправильное количество товаров - от некорректного формирования либо хранения переопределённых данных.

Comment: Вы не правы. На сайте получается, что первый обработчик получает кол-во товаров. Затем второй. Затем первый изменяет к-во товара. Затем второй. Вот и проблема.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку на самом деле вам не нужно блокировать чтение до появления новой записи, а только нужно заблокировать конкурентное чтение последнего id_order для приращения счётчика, то `select .. for update` будет достаточно.

```
begin;
select id_order from tablename where /**/ order by id_order limit 1 for update
insert ...
commit;
```

Блокировка на строку `for update` (как и остальные транзакционные блокировки) берётся только на время действия всей транзакции целиком и освобождаются при commit или rollback.

Конкурентный ждущий `select id_order .. for update` изменение таблицы увидит и вернёт после коммита той транзакции уже новый `id_order`

---

Или можно пойти в оптимистичные блокировки. Повесить на `id_order` уникальный индекс, получить id_order без блокировки, сделать +1 и попытаться записать новую строку. Если СУБД сказала дубликат ключа - вернуться к шагу прочтения id_order и повторить. Разумеется, будет работать отвратно при высокой конкурентности. Но если конфликты крайне редки и рассматриваются как исключение из правила - то работать будет.

Comment: Глупый вопрос - я могу с точки зрения PHP разделить транзакцию на части? Т.е. Саначала begin и select for update, затем просчеты в PHP и как второй запрос insert и commit?

Comment: Повесить уникальный индекс на `id_order` невозможно. `id` уже уникальный

Comment: @user64675 В таблице только один первичный ключ. Но уникальных индексов может быть сколько угодно

Comment: Вариант с begin..commit мне кажется самым удачным. Вопрос в том - можно ли его разделить на 2 запроса (с точки зрения PHP). Иначе смысла в этом нет

Comment: На стороне PHP для управления транзакцией вообще отдельные методы API `PDO::beginTransaction`, `PDO::commit` и `PDO::rollBack`. Между - любое число любых запросов по этому соединению будут в этой транзакции.

Comment: А есть не через PDO, а через подобный mysql_query?
Или это будет `mysql_query('START TRANSACTION')`?
Т.е. если выполнять транзакцию методами PHP, лок в ней сохранится?

Comment: Наверное будет работать со start transaction. Проверьте. Расширение mysql_* уже лет 10 как не поддерживается и уже с годик удалено из PHP. Штатной поддержки апи транзакций точно нет.